# Is there a such thing as optional types in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and working on creating a schema for a table in postgresql. There are columns in the table can be optional, but I don't know of a way to set it as optional other than making it nullable, e.g.,

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  optional_column INT -- null if not provided (i.e., optional)
);
```

In postgresql, or SQL in general, is this the canonical approach to making a column nullable?

Comment: [setting a default value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-default.html) for that field should be enough, either with null or any other data type.

Comment: A table consists of a fixed set of **columns**. Just use NULL for undefined values.

Answer (score 3):

Making a column nullable **is** making it optional.

In PostgreSQL, a NULL value uses no extra storage space.

If you don't want to insert a value in `col2`, just omit it from the column list:

```
INSERT INTO tab (col1, col3) VALUES (1, 42);
```

Comment: Probably should show how to insert data without providing a value for a particular column. *(In my experience, most beginners don't know how.)*

Comment: INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1, default, 42) works as well as INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1, NULL, 42) in case there is no explicit default value for col2, because the default default value (sic!) is NULL.